# browserExtension: Why can I not export a key that has been generated in the background script in the content script?

Tags: serialization, content-script, browser-extension, webcrypto-api

I'm playing around with browser extensions and the web crypto api.

When exporting a key that has been sent from the background script to the content script of my browser extension I get an error `Argument 2 does not implement interface CryptoKey`.

My assumption is that this has something to do with either `CryptoKey` not being serializable with the unstructured clone algorithm or `CryptoKey` not being serializable for security reasons, is this correct?

I could just keep the keys in the background script anyway, so I already have a solution to the problem. This has been quite painful to debug though, so I would at least like to know the reason this failed ..

content-script.js:

```
window.addEventListener('click', async function() {
  console.log("start content script");
  let key = await browser.runtime.sendMessage({
    name: "AES-GCM",
  });
  console.log("key", JSON.stringify(Array.from(new Uint8Array(await crypto.subtle.exportKey('raw', key)))))
  console.log("key loaded");
})

console.log("content script loaded");
```

background-script.js:

```
console.log("background script started");
async function generateKey() { 
  console.log("generate key");
  let keySecret = crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(32));
  return await crypto.subtle.importKey(
    "raw",
    keySecret,
    "AES-GCM",
    true,
    ["encrypt"]
  );
}

function handler(message, sender, sendResponse) {
  return generateKey();
}

browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(handler);
```

Comment: You should post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that a repro is possible. The code fragment so far is not enough. The output looks OK.

Comment: Thank you, the problem was indeed somewhere else and I updated the question